# EasyPHP - Unexpected end of Apache

Tags: apache, easyphp

Estou tentando iniciar o EasyPHP, mas o Apache tá mostrando esse erro.
Nos logs do EasyPHP aparecem a seguinte mensagem:

**EasyPHP ServerBase::TimerProc : GetProcessVersion Apache (pid: 11332) error 5**

Já verifiquei os processos que estavam executando, mas nenhum estava na porta 80.

Comment: provavelmente o seu endereço IP mudou. E em algum lugar, nos arquivos de configuração do EasyPHP, tens o IP antigo definido

Comment: Outra causa pode ser que a porta 80 está a ser ocupada por outro processo. Tens o Skype a rodar? se sim, sugiro fechar primeiro o Skype

Comment: Tenho não, psantos. Sabe dizer em qual parte do arquivo posso achar essa configuração do IP?